# How to reference mavenLocal build of korge-next for my Korge project?

Tags: korge

How would I setup the gradle configuration stuff so it references the stuff in the .m2 folder?

[image]

I tried referencing the version like so:

[image]

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'KorgeClient'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.soywiz.korlibs.korge.plugins:korge-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.999.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.soywiz.korlibs.korge.plugins:korge-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.999 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 16, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.3.3' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korge.plugins:korge-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.999 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 16
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.3.3')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.soywiz.korlibs.korge.plugins:korge-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.999 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 16
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.3.3')

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'KorgeClient'.
```

...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because I was building korge-next using java 17 rather than java 16.

After switching to building with java 16, I am able to reference the mavenLocal version.

Here's the setting that I needed to change:

[image]